# Cannot render component images in component when using or mapping on state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-typescript

I am having trouble understanding why I cannot get images to show up in my components. I have a boolean which indicates loading, and an array that gets filled async. When I finish, I set the boolean and the component re renders. Now, I want to create a card for each item in the array and put in in a card deck (this is from react-bootstrap if that wasn't obvious). I can do this with any given boolean and array, but not with the boolean and arrays created with `React.useState`... Why is that and how should I go about fixing this?

I encountered this problem quite a few hours ago, and have tracked down its source to this minimal working example that still reflects what I am trying to do, but I am unsure of what to do from here.

```
function TestCard() {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Card.Img src="holder.js/200x200" />
    </Card>
  );
}
```

I am trying to render the following component:

```
function MainComponent() {
  const [boolState, setBoolState] = React.useState(false);
  const [arrayState, setArrayState] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setBoolState(true);
      setArrayState([1,2,3]);
    }, 2000);
  });

  return (
    <>
    {/* This works */}
    {
      true &&
      <CardDeck>
        {
          [1,2,3].map(_ => {
            return (
              <TestCard />
            );
          })
        }
      </CardDeck>
    }

    {/* This doesn't, why? */}
    {
      boolState &&
      <CardDeck>
        {
          arrayState.map(_ => {
            return (
              <TestCard />
            );
          })
        }
      </CardDeck>
    }

    </>
  );
}
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cannot-render-component-images-in-component-when-using-or-mapping-on-state-varia-forked-lt1oc)

Comment: i've tried your logic in my simulation code. no problem. can you put a breakpoint in devtools and troubleshoot whether the component re-render when you do setBoolState and setArrayState

Comment: Code (sans the image) appears to work fine here in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cannot-render-component-images-in-component-when-using-or-mapping-on-state-varia-rij9d). What is `holder.js`? Perhaps if you update your question with your real code and issue we can better assist you.

Comment: @DrewReese This is verbatim my code. I did `create-react-app`, `npm install holderjs` and `import holderjs` at the top. Holderjs is a placeholder image tool. I fixed the code to how it looks on my end in your sandbox, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cannot-render-component-images-in-component-when-using-or-mapping-on-state-varia-forked-lt1oc?file=/src/App.js) is the fork. It doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @KevinMoeMyintMyat It definitely hits the return statement after the setStates. I checked that with ReactDevTools in chrome. You can see a live example in the code sandbox.

Comment: Maybe this help: https://github.com/imsky/holder/issues/225 Seems there's an issue with using holderjs and react component lifecycle.

Comment: @DrewReese Hmm.. it does seem to be an issue with holderjs... I used Placeholder.com and that seemed to work just fine. I'm probably going to submit an issue because I feel like this should work.

Comment: Yeah, TBH holderjs seems a little buggy. On my machine I was suffering this [high CPU issue](https://github.com/imsky/holder/issues/229) when trying to validate fixes from the issue I linked you and my browser locked up twice and didn't seem worth it to dig further.

Comment: @DrewReese It's unfortunate. Holder is used in a lot of docs such as bootstrap's docs and would be so useful to use in my case. Anyways, I guess I'll just scrap the idea and move on. Thank you.

Comment: Be aware that bootstrap is a JS solution, whereas react-bootstrap is an abstraction on top of that. AFAIK holderjs lives in the vanilla js world so getting it to also play nicely with React and it not working so well isn't a complete surprise to me.

Comment: @DrewReese The react-bootstrap docs use holder as well, so I thought it'd be safe enough to use.